# Traer datos de un web service el cual devuelve un map + Angular

Tags: angular

Necesito de su gran ayuda, estoy tratando de hacer una validaciones en un web services de perfiles el cual devuelve un map con un código pero la verdad no he podido hacer que me retorne ese código para hacer el condicional con los códigos autorizados.

La consulta esta bien ya que me saca respuesta 200 y la respuesta esta en el response del navegador pero necesito sacar ese información por pantalla la cual la devuelve pero no se como sacarla ella se almacena en el navegador en la pestaña Preview la cual se pude ver en la consola de Chrome donde se inspecciona el código.

**Service**

Este es el web service donde la petición esta ok pero no se, si hay que añadir algo para que salga el código para realizar el condicional de los perfiles creo que hay que añadirle para que retorne un map con los datos que devuelve el response.

```
  urlPerfil = `${this.autPerfiles}`;
  perfiles(usuario: string): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ usuario: usuario });
    const body = { usuario: String };
    return this.http
      .post<InterAuthPerfiles>(this.urlPerfil, body, { headers: headers })
      .pipe(
        map((resp) => {
          return this.http.get<InterAuthPerfiles[]>(this.urlPerfil);

          console.log(resp.cdPerf + 'Código del usuario');
        }),
        catchError((err) => of(false))
      );
  }
```

Esta es la clase donde voy hacer el condicional con el código, necesito saber como capturar el código de la respuesta hay que añadir para que retorne un map con los datos del response que retorna el webService como se muestra mas abajo donde lo tengo relacionado.

```
this.authService
  .perfiles(this.miFormulario.value.usuario)
  .pipe(map((response) => response))
  .subscribe((Response) => {
    console.log(Response);
  });
```

**Interface**

```
export interface InterAuthPerfiles {
  usuario: string;
  cdPerf: string;
  ok?: any;
}
```

Esta es la salida la cual sale por el navegador
La cual sale sin datos aunque si se conecta al web service, necesito saber como hago para traer los datos del response.

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

Esta es la salida del Response por PostMan, necesito capturar el campo cdPerf de esta respuesta y sacarlo por pantalla. creo que debo cambiar la respuesta que es un boolean a una de tipo map pero la verdad no me a funcionado.

Respuesta Postman y también sale con mi consulta en el navegador en la pestaña Preview

```
{
    200
    [
        {cdPerf: 999, deNombPerf: "Inicial"}, 
        {cdPerf: 304, deNombPerf: "Ingeniero de Desarrollo"}
    ]
}
```

como ven la salida del postman necesito saber como saco la respuesta del webservice por pantalla html del angular necesito capturar el cdPerf, el cual en el backend es un map.

Gracias y quedo atento.

----> todo bien ya me funciono, ahora necesito sacar un dato de la respuesta el campo cdPerf para hacer una validación en el archivo ts
Ejemplo, como el if de abajo pero no me funciona el codigo resp[1].cdPerf para recorres la respuesta

if(resp[1].cdPerf || 999, 304, 87, 143, 124, 251, 123, 122)){

```
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/consultar');

    } else {
      
    retutn this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth/home');
```

{
200
[
{cdPerf: 999, deNombPerf: "Inicial"},
{cdPerf: 304, deNombPerf: "Ingeniero de Desarrollo"}
]
}

---Este es el error que me sale cuando ejecuto la búsqueda con la sentencia resp[1].cdPerf

Error: src/app/auth/pages/login/login.component.ts:74:28 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '1' can't be used to index type 'boolean | InterAuthPerfiles | Observable<InterAuthPerfiles[]>'.
Property '1' does not exist on type 'boolean | InterAuthPerfiles | Observable<InterAuthPerfiles[]>'.

```
74              console.table(resp[1].cdPerf);
```

Gracias y quedo atento.

Comment: ¿Y dónde esta lo que te responde la consulta?

Comment: El código llega al punto donde se vuelve algo confuso, luego tienes `this.authService.perfiles.arguments.salidaPerfiles.getcdPerf` que no se de donde sacas el `getcdPerf`, mejora tu pregunta para que sea más fácil ayudarte y revisa [ask].

Comment: ok Gracias, ya la acomode mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores y malas prácticas que complican el código:

1. Envías la misma información dos veces, el usuario en `headers` y `body`.
2. En el `map` que utilizas en tu petición `post` mandas a que haga una petición `get` que regresa un arreglo, nunca regresas ni utilizas los datos que obtienes de la petición `post` original. No tiene sentido.
3. Tienes un `console.log` después del `return` ¿Cómo vas a revisar lo que trae tu respuesta si regresas antes de imprimir en consola?
4. En el componente o clase donde lo utilizas tienes: `map((response) => response)` el cual no hace nada. Pides que transforme los datos de `response` en datos de `response`. Esto se utiliza para extraer los datos, puedes usar `response.cdPerf` para obtener el valor que buscas.
5. La impresión en consola que pusiste `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}`, esto ni siquiera tiene que ver con el código, estás imprimiendo el objeto Observable.

Parece que lo que quieres hacer es obtener todos los perfiles, podrías intentar con algo así:

**Servicio**

```
  url = `${this.autPerfiles}`;
  perfiles() {
    return this.http.get<InterAuthPerfiles[]>(this.url);
  }
```

**Componente**

```
    this.authService.perfiles().subscribe({
      next: (resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.log('Error');
      },
    });
```

A partir de ahí ya extraes lo que quieras, parece que tu respuesta JSON trae un arreglo de objetos, entonces necesitarías algo así como `resp[0].cdPerf`, pero dadas las circunstancias no queda claro que necesitas y pretendes hacer, si obtener datos de todos los perfiles o de un solo perfil.

Recomiendo leer detenidamente [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), una buena pregunta hace que sea más fácil poderte ayudar de mejor forma, así como limpiar el código y proveer información clara, concisa y relevante respecto al problema que tienes.

Comment: Excelente gracias funciono ya tengo los datos . ahora estoy tratando de sacar el campo cdPerf ya que con el comando no me funciono.

Comment: ¿La petición `get` te regreso todos los datos? ¿Los datos como los usas, usas un `*ngFor` para iterar sobre ellos o como los muestras en el HTML? Actualiza el código de la pregunta para ver qué más se puede hacer especificando donde tienes el problema.